# Python List length as a string

Tags: python, string, conventions

Is there a preferred (not ugly) way of outputting a list length as a string? Currently I am nesting function calls like so:

```
print "Length: %s" % str(len(self.listOfThings))
```

This seems like a hack solution, is there a more graceful way of achieving the same result?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need the call to `str`:

```
print "Length: %s" % len(self.listOfThings)
```

Note that using `%` is being deprecated, and you should prefer to use `str.format` if you are using Python 2.6 or newer:

```
print "Length: {0}".format(len(self.listOfThings))
```

Answer (score 2):

`"Length: %d" % len(self.listOfThings)` should work great.

The point of string formatting is to make your data into a string, so calling `str` is not what you want: provide the data itself, in this case an `int`. An `int` can be formatted many ways, the most common being `%d`, which provides a decimal representation of it (the way we're used to looking at numbers). For arbitrary stuff you can use `%s`, which calls `str` on the object being represented; calling `str` yourself should never be necessary.

I would also consider `"Length: %d" % (len(self.listOfThings),)`—some people habitually use tuples as the argument to `str.__mod__` because the way it works is sort of funny and they want to provide something more consistent.

If I was using `print` in particular, I might just use `print "Length:",  len(self.listOfThings)`. I seldom actually use `print`, though.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can leave out the `str()` call, but that's about it. How come is calling functions "a hack"?

Comment: it just looks ugly, and i have often found that python has more streamlined ways of doing things than I think of